# Using combinations in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, combinations

I have the following columns of which I want to make combinations using two elements at a time:

```
numeric_cols = ['clump_thickness', 'a', 'b']
```

I am taking combinations using the following function

```
from itertools import combinations
def combinations2(x):
    return combinations(x,2)
```

I am using the `combinations2` along with `map`

```
numeric_cols_sc = sc.parallelize(numeric_cols)
numeric_cols_sc.map(combinations2).flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

I was expecting an output on length 3 -

```
[('clump_thickness', 'a'), ('clump_thickness', 'b'), ('a','b')]
```

But what I get is-

```
numeric_cols_sc.map(combinations2).flatMap(lambda x: x).take(3)
# [('c', 'l'), ('c', 'u'), ('c', 'm')]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your spark version is not running `combinations2` on elements of `numeric_cols`, it's running it on each element (which you made a record in the rdd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `combinations2` is dissimilar when you do it with spark.

You should either make that list a single record:

```
numeric_cols_sc = sc.parallelize([numeric_cols])
```

Or use Spark's operations, such as cartesian (example below will require additional transformation):

```
numeric_cols_sc = sc.parallelize(numeric_cols)
numeric_cols_sc.cartesian(numeric_cols_sc)
```

Comment: The problem with `.cartesian` is that it will include diagonal pairs (such as `('clump_thickness', 'clump_thickness')`) and each possible pair will be included in the two possible orientations (for instance `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'a')` will both be included). You can filter all these out with `filter`: `numeric_cols_sc.cartesian(numeric_cols_sc).filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1])`. I guess this is the "require[d] additional transformation" which you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this algorithm, but with higher numbers looks like that doesn't work or its very slow. It will run in a cluster of big data(cloudera), so I think that I have to put the function into pyspark, please give a hand if you can.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as itts

number_list = [10953, 10423, 10053]

def reducer(nums):
  def ranges(n):
    print(n)
    return range(n, -1, -1)

  num_list = list(map(ranges, nums))
  return list(itts.product(*num_list))

data=pd.DataFrame(reducer(number_list))
print(data)
```